# TreeView NodeStyle add Image Alt Text Web Accessibility Issue

Tags: c#, vb.net, image, webforms, treeview

I have never worked on Web Forms so my question might not be so constructive to the community but I'm trying to add text to the alt for a Node Style  Image attached below:

[image]

This is the Error I'm getting in Web Accessibility

[image]

Update:
I have already tried adding alt="text", but  it throws an error.

Comment: I'd suggest you simply put the code here and ditch the images.

Comment: Hi, I'm working on a remote machine which do not allow me to  copy the code actually

Comment: Why is it tagged winforms??

Comment: oh sorry my mistake, I meant to tag web forms

Answer (score 0):

I haven't worked with this, but did you try placing

> alt="text"

in the nodestyle tag, and then closing that tag?